# How can I toggle JS .text

Tags: javascript, toggle

I have this function that shows the ALT of an image on img click. How can I toggle this function and hide the #show when there will be a Self.close click that hides the lightbox?

```js
$("img").on("click", function() {
  $("#show").text($(this).attr("alt"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="show"></div>
<img src="https://blogs-images.forbes.com/ericsavitz/files/2011/03/smiley-face.jpg" alt="SMILE">
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution:

```js
$("img").on("click", function() {
    var alt = $(this).attr("alt");
    $("#show").text($("#show").text() === alt ? '' : alt);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="show"></div>
<img src="https://blogs-images.forbes.com/ericsavitz/files/2011/03/smiley-face.jpg" alt="SMILE">
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep track of which state it's currently in. There's a number of ways of doing this but this is likely the easiest:

```js
var isShowingText = false;
$("img").on("click", function() {
  if (isShowingText) {
    $('#show').text('');
  } else {
    $("#show").text($(this).attr("alt"));
  }
  
  // Toggle the flag. false becomes true, true becomes false
  isShowingText = !isShowingText;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="show"></div>
<img src="https://blogs-images.forbes.com/ericsavitz/files/2011/03/smiley-face.jpg" alt="SMILE">
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by setting the text to nothing if it is filled using:

```
$('#show').text('');
```

Example:

```js
$('img').on('click', function () {
  $('#show').text($('#show').text() === '' ? $(this).attr('alt') : '');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="show"></div>
<img src="https://blogs-images.forbes.com/ericsavitz/files/2011/03/smiley-face.jpg" alt="SMILE">
```

**EDIT:**
Another solution might be to toggle a CSS class:

```js
// Set the alt text
$('span').text($(this).attr('alt'));

$('img').on('click', function () {
  $('span').toggleClass('hide');
});
```

```css
.span {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="hide"></span>
<img src="https://blogs-images.forbes.com/ericsavitz/files/2011/03/smiley-face.jpg" alt="SMILE">
```